# How do I calculate page table size?

Tags: operating-system

I would like to know how to calculate the size of the page table (in bytes) if there is one entry per page, each entry requires 4 bytes and my page size is 64KB.

Comment: A page table is supposed to have more than 1 entry in it, otherwise it's useless. Please recheck your assignment and correct the question.

Answer (score 16):

Size of PageTable (bytes) = Number of Entries in PageTable * Size of Entry

Number of Entries in PageTable = Size of Memory / PageSize

Size of Entry = 4 Bytes in this case.

Plug and Chug.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't clearly specify what you mean with KB you could mean either a kilo[byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) (kB), that is 1000 bytes, and kibi[byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) (KiB). that is 1024 bytes.

Pagetable size in bytes can be calculated through [multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication).

Comment: Well, if KAR is talking about pages and page tables, then it seems obvious to me that they mean 1024.

Comment: If I ever actually meet anyone on the street that uses "KiB", I will beat them to death with a piece of wet celery (to make my pleasure more long-lived). A kilobyte is 1024 here.

Comment: @Spoike, thank you for the wikipedia link about multiplication, I did learn a lot :p

Answer (score 0):

Number-of-pages * page-table-entry-size should give the answer. The page table just contains addresses of pages; page size is irrelevant.

So if you have 1000 pages then the page table size is 4*1000, if you have 1000000 pages then its 4*1000000.

Comment: @KAR: By the definition you have given in your original question, each page table entry is 4 bytes, and there is one entry for each page. Therefore, if you have 1000 pages, then the page table has 1000 entries and each one is 4 bytes. That makes 4000 bytes.

That's a very small memory. Now work it out for your current system.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not so simple, doesn't have each page table entry something like valid, reference, or dirty bits, if all 3 are included the table for 1000 pages would have to have size like 1000x(4x8+3) in bits. Let me know if I am correct because this is my homework also ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Size of page table =no. of page table entry*size of one entry .
No of page table entry =logical address space /size of one page